# Django admin extra field Sum() TimeField

Tags: python, django, time, django-admin, sum

In Django Admin i want to display the sum of all action durations. I solved it wirh an extra field. But the sum of

01:30:00 h
03:45:00 h

are summed to 47500,0 because sum converts times to integer.

I changed my admin.py like it is described here: 
[django-admin: Add extra row with totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541956/django-admin-add-extra-row-with-totals)

```
class MyChangeList(ChangeList):

    def get_results(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyChangeList, self).get_results(*args, **kwargs)
    q = self.result_list.aggregate(status_sum=Sum('duration'))
    self.status_count = q['action_sum']

...

class ActionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_changelist(self, request):
    return MyChangeList

class Meta:
    model = Status

list_display = ('name', 'duration')
```

**Duration** is defienes as TimeField in modles.py:

```
class Action (models.Model):

    duration = models.TimeField()
```

Somebody knows how to change aggregate() function in MyChangeList ?
I think i have to change time values to float or integer, make the sum and then convert it back.

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are using MySQL. It has an [old bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12108) on summing up times (I don't know if it's fixed now).

You can store the duration in minutes (or 15-minutes if it's ok). Or you can use [django-durationfield](http://django-durationfield.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: I'm using Mysql. I think it's the bug with mysql you mentioned.  
Thanks a lot, i installed **django-durationfield** and changed the last two lines in MyChangeList to:  
  
    <code>class MyChangeList(ChangeList):  
          
        ...  
  
        q = self.result_list.aggregate(status_sum=Sum('duration'))  
        self.status_count = timedelta(microseconds=q['action_sum'])    
  
  </code>
Now it works ;-)