# Can I disable (not remove) a particular row in a django-admin result?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I am using [dfrdmn's neat hack to add a summary row to a Django admin view](http://dfrdmn.com/post/55104336478/adding-summary-row-in-django-admin). Briefly, it overrides the `ChangeList` for the `ModelAdmin` to append a new item to `self.result_list._result_cache`

However, this row is treated like other rows in that:

- it has a selection box (for performing actions on it)
- it has clickable link fields (for opening the edit view)
- it has editable fields (for same-page edits)
- it is considered part of the result_list when clicking Save (which results in an error)

[image: admin result with actionable summary row - fields to disable are highlighted]

How can I disable all of these so that the row is view-only, not selectable and ignored when saving?

As a bonus, displaying nothing for the "Like" field would be nice but is a low priority. (It's a NullBooleanField.)

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541956/django-admin-add-extra-row-with-totals

Comment: maybe https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-admin-changelist-stats

Comment: django-admin-changelist-stats doesn't support aggregates on related fields e.g. Sum('daymenuitem__meal__cost') fails

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#model-admin-methods