# Add an extra total row in admin - Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

`admin.py` for an app is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db.models import Subquery, Sum, OuterRef

from .models import GoodsItem, FinishedGoodsItem, SoldGoodsItem

@admin.register(SoldGoodsItem)
class SoldGoodsItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('date', 'goods_item', 'weight')
    list_display = ('date', 'goods_item', 'weight')

@admin.register(FinishedGoodsItem)
class FinishedGoodsItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('date', 'goods_item', 'weight')
    list_display = ('date', 'goods_item', 'weight')

@admin.register(GoodsItem)
class GoodsItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__', 'finished_good', 'sold_good', 'stock_available')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(GoodsItemAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(
            finished_good = Subquery(FinishedGoodsItem.objects.filter(goods_item=OuterRef('pk'))\
                .values('goods_item_id').annotate(sum=Sum('weight')).values('sum')[:1]),
            sold_good = Subquery(SoldGoodsItem.objects.filter(goods_item=OuterRef('pk'))\
                .values('goods_item_id').annotate(sum=Sum('weight')).values('sum')[:1])
        )
        return qs

    def finished_good(self, obj):
        return obj.finished_good

    def sold_good(self, obj):
        return obj.sold_good

    def stock_available(self, obj):
        finished_good = 0 if self.finished_good(obj) is None else self.finished_good(obj)
        sold_good = 0 if self.sold_good(obj) is None else self.sold_good(obj)
        return '-' if (finished_good == 0 and sold_good == 0) else finished_good - sold_good

admin.site.site_header = 'Rajeshwari Steels'
```

For `GoodsItemAdmin`, I want to display an extra row with the totals at the bottom of the records table. The total row should display the total for all three columns, which are `finished_good`, `sold_good` and `stock_available`.
Here all three columns are displayed using methods in `GoodsItemAdmin` and are annotated on queryset by overriding `get_queryset` method.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541956/django-admin-add-extra-row-with-totals), while searched for the solution. The answers for that question suggest to override admin template and `changelist_view` method.

Help me that how can I override admin template and `changelist_view` method for displaying totals row for annotated columns on queryset.
If there is any another nice solution to do this, let me know that also.